# Uploading multiple artifacts from a gradle project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an AndroidStudio project, containing a main module "app" an android library "baseapp" and another an android library "networking" - which depends on "baseapp". I would like both libraries to be compiled and their artifacts to be uploaded to a maven repository. "app" is a sample app that consumes both "baseapp" and "networking".

As the maven repo is actually a git repo, I'm using the [wagon-git](https://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/) plugin and [this script](https://github.com/JeroenMols/GitAsMaven/blob/master/publish-bitbucket.gradle) described [here](http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/).

This is the project structure:

[image]

Main app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    compile "com.locassa.android.baseapp:baseapp:$rootProject.artifactVersionName"
    compile "com.locassa.android.baseapp:networking:$rootProject.artifactVersionName"
}
```

Networking's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"

    compile "com.locassa.android.baseapp:baseapp:$rootProject.artifactVersionName"
}
```

When I launch my `./gradlew uploadArchives` command, build fails when "networking" artifact gets compiled because "baseapp" hasn't been uploaded yet. I would have thought I could compile and upload "baseapp" and only after that compile and upload "networking" but this is not happening. I'm not sure if this is because "networking" is compiled before "baseapp" or because gradle will check all dependencies before executing anything.

Unfortunately my knowledge of gradle is limited and all my attempts based on other SO questions didn't quite work out.

Does anyone know why this is happening or a way to set a priority in gradle so that "app" can be uploaded even if "networking" has an unsatisfied dependency or optionally how to force "app" to be uploaded ignoring or disabling "networking"?

I would like the two artifacts to have the same version as it's easier to use and maintain, so I cannot have "networking" to reference a previous version of "app".

Hope it's clear, but otherwise I'm happy to integrate with more info.

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do is called transitive dependency, you can do it with gradle and bintray,

Comment: Thanks @BabajideApata, I would have thought it could be sorted with gradle only, which would be great as I'm not currently using bintray

Comment: What did you set `ARTIFACT_NAME` as in your gradle.properties?

Comment: @BenPearson: each library has its own `ARTIFACT_NAME`, for "baseapp" is baseapp and for "networking" is networking. They are defined in a gradle.properties file in each library. Each library is self contained and works in isolation - probably the easiest workaround would be to have the two libs in two completely different projects so I can upload them independenlty.... but keeping the same version would be more complicated, and I didn't expect to have this problem initially

Comment: Hi @Guido, I think it's because of the way the apps dependency structure since networking depends on baseapp why can't you open base app as a different project and upload baseapp at first, then follow by networking, before your app. I think it should work like this

Comment: Thanks @BabajideApata, I think I'll end up doing like that.... but it looks like a workaround rather than an elegant solution: f.i. both project will have to maintain the same version number, which is easy but prone to mistakes and possibly forgetting it. If version name is not the same, it gets even worse as every version of "networking" will work only with specific versions of "base" which becomes kind of unmaintainable.